# Change background color of Tab bar in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to change the background color of the tab bar in flutter, I have tried the following ( which was accepted as an answer on this forum ) but it didnt work:

here is the code

```
   return new MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      primaryColor: Colors.pink[800], //Changing this will change the color of  the TabBar
      accentColor: Colors.cyan[600],
    ),
```

EDIT :

When I change the theme data colors the background color doesnt change. Im trying to create a horizontal scrolling sub menu underneath the app bar and it was suggested I use a Tab bar.

Here is the entire dart file:

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

  class Index extends StatelessWidget {

//final User user;

  // HomeScreen({Key key, @required this.user}) : super(key: key);

  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     // TODO: implement build
    // String emoji = emojify(":cool:");
   return new MaterialApp(
     theme: new ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
       primaryColor: Colors.white, //Changing this will change the color of     the TabBar
      accentColor: Colors.cyan[600],
     ),

    home: DefaultTabController(
    length: 2,
  child: Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
     backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0099a9),
     title: new Image.asset('images/lb_appbar_small.png', fit: BoxFit.none,),
     bottom: TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab( text: "Tab 1",),
            Tab(text: "Tab 2"),
             ],       
     ),
  ),
    body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            //ROW 1
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                child: IconButton(
                     icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.checkSquare,),
                     iconSize: 60.0,
                     color: const Color(0xFF0099a9),
                      onPressed: () { print("Pressed"); }
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                     icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.glasses,),
                     iconSize: 60.0,
                     color: const Color(0xFF0099a9),
                      onPressed: () { print("Pressed"); }
                  )

              ),
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                     icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.moon,),
                     iconSize: 60.0,
                     color: const Color(0xFF0099a9),
                      onPressed: () { print("Pressed"); 
                      Text("Check Out");
                      }
                  )

              ),
            ]
          ),
          Row(//ROW 2
              children: [
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                     icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.users,),
                     iconSize: 60.0,
                     color: const Color(0xFF0099a9),
                      onPressed: () { print("Pressed"); }
                  )

              ),
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                     icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.trophy,),
                     iconSize: 60.0,
                     color: const Color(0xFF0099a9),
                      onPressed: () { print("Pressed"); }
                  )

              ),
             Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                     icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.calendar,),
                     iconSize: 60.0,
                     color: const Color(0xFF0099a9),
                      onPressed: () { print("Pressed"); }
                  )

              )
          ]),
          Row(// ROW 3
              children: [
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                     icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.fileExcel,),
                     iconSize: 60.0,
                     color: const Color(0xFF0099a9),
                      onPressed: () { print("Pressed"); }
                  )

              ),
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                     icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.shoppingCart,),
                     iconSize: 60.0,
                     color: const Color(0xFF0099a9),
                      onPressed: () { print("Pressed"); }
                  )

              ),
             Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                     icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.list,),
                     iconSize: 60.0,
                     color: const Color(0xFF0099a9),
                      onPressed: () { print("Pressed"); }
                  )

              ),
          ]),
        ],
        ),


 bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
    items: [
      new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.feedback, color: const Color(0xFF0099a9),),
          title: new Text("feedback")
      ),
      new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.help, color: const Color(0xFF0099a9),),
          title: new Text("help")
      ),
      new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.people, color: const Color(0xFF0099a9),),
          title: new Text("community",)
       )
     ]
    )







         )
   )
 );






  }
}
```

Comment: could you put your code sample in the question ?

Comment: I did but if you want the whole dart file I'll edit it and add it.

Comment: I added the entire dart file. thanks @diegoveloper

Comment: what color do you want?

Comment: just white, Im trying to achieve a desgin like Quora.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the `TabBar` inside your `AppBar` for that reason it take the same color, just move the `TabBar` outside the `Appbar`

```
    Scaffold(
                    appBar: new AppBar(
                      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0099a9),
                      title: new Image.asset(
                        'images/lb_appbar_small.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                    body: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TabBar(
                          tabs: [
                            Tab(
                              text: "Tab 1",
                            ),
                            Tab(text: "Tab 2"),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                            //ROW 1
                         ....
```

Comment: Put `TabBar` inside `body`, then it worked well!

Answer (score 3):

Hi you are getting same color since you have added tabbar in appbar,If you are looking for different color for both `TabBar` and `Appbar`. Here is what you have to do.
*Add TabBar in body of `Scafold`.
Sample Code:

```
    class _SwapOfferPageState extends State<SwapOfferPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Swap or Offer shift"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(      // Column
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Color(0xffF5F5F5),        // Tab Bar color change
            child: TabBar(           // TabBar
              controller: _tabController,
              labelColor: const Color(0xff959595),
              indicatorWeight: 2,
              indicatorColor: Color(0xff4961F6),
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(
                  text: "SWAP MY SHIFT",
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: "OFFER MY SHIFT",
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: TabBarView(         // Tab Bar View
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _tabController,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Tab1'),
                Text('Tab2'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change the Tabbar background-color, when Tabbar is inside the Material widget.

```
                Material(
                  color: Colors.white, //Tabbar background-color
                  child: TabBar(
                    isScrollable: true,
                    labelStyle: Theme.of(context).tabBarTheme.labelStyle,
                    unselectedLabelStyle:
                        Theme.of(context).tabBarTheme.unselectedLabelStyle,
                    labelColor: Theme.of(context).tabBarTheme.labelColor,
                    unselectedLabelColor:
                        Theme.of(context).tabBarTheme.unselectedLabelColor,
                    indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(text: 'tab 1'),
                      Tab(text: 'tab 2'),
                      Tab(text: 'tab 3'),
                      Tab(text: 'tab 4'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is still looking for How to separate a `TabBar` from `Appbar` , please check the below code-

```
appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text("some title"),
    body: new Column(
        children: [
            /// this is will not colored with theme data
            new TabBar(...),
            Expanded(
                new TabBarView(...)
            )
        ]
    )
)
```

Answer (score -3):

Or you can even simply wrap the TabBar in a Container widget, and apply the "color" you want.

Comment: You can't, because Container does not implement the PreferredSizeWidget